# Can TextArea widget be resized by mouse at runtime?

Tags: qooxdoo

I am wondering can qx.ui.form.TextArea be resized by mouse at runtime? just as I can re-height question box in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have also a look ate the Resizer Demo:
http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#widget~Resizer.html

Regards, 
Chris

Answer (score 2):

sure thats possible. It depends on the outer layout you use. [Take a look at the following code example.](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/playground/#%7B%22code%22:%20%22var%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window%28%2522First%2520Window%2522%29%253B%250Awin.setWidth%28300%29%253B%250Awin.setHeight%28200%29%253B%250Awin.setShowMinimize%28false%29%253B%250A%250Athis.getRoot%28%29.add%28win%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A20%252C%2520top%253A20%257D%29%253B%250Awin.open%28%29%253B%250A%250Awin.setLayout%28new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas%28%29%29%253B%250Awin.add%28new%2520qx.ui.form.TextArea%28%29%252C%2520%257Bedge%253A%25200%257D%29%253B%22%7D)

```
var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("First Window");
win.setWidth(300);
win.setHeight(200);
win.setShowMinimize(false);

this.getRoot().add(win, {left:20, top:20});
win.open();

win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Canvas());
win.add(new qx.ui.form.TextArea(), {edge: 0});​
```

It adds a textarea to a window containing a canvas layout. The Layout property edge : 0 keeps the textarea stick to the edges of the window. Resizing the window now also resizes the textarea. The same can be done without a window.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: its good example to auto resize widgets with outer layout but I was interested to resize textarea with mouse. Chirstian suggests an accurate solution.